# How to make jquery Autocomplete work for a class library and SharePoint

Tags: c#, ajax, jquery-ui, sharepoint, dll

We have custom code behind code (deployed as DLLs in GAC) for some pages on one of our SharePoint 2007 sites.

Getting the jquery UI autocomplete plugin to work on an ASP.NET application was a breeze but I am having hard time recreating similar functionality for a SharePoint page. The data resides in a SQL Server table.

Do I need to configure the web.config for ASP.NET 2.0 AJAX Extensions 1.0 even though the code is not using any of that?

Any help/pointers are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a point in your app where you can print out the data needed by the autocomplete.

I don't know how you exactly integrated your code into SP, do you have the ability to use

```
Response.Write("whatever"); 
Response.End();
```

at some stage in your page (PageLoad for example) and just get "whatever" as output, no master template surrounding it?

Then you can check for an incoming request var and print the data needed by the autocomplete:

```
if(Request["printautocomplete"]=="true"){
    Response.Write("my autocomplete data as string"); 
    Response.End(); 
}
```

Comment: I meant to ask about making server side ajax calls on Sharepoint on page whose codebehind resides in a DLL in GAC.